# Flutter qlaver routing, unable to refresh / reload page

Tags: flutter, routes

I have implemented https://pub.dev/packages/qlevar_router, for lazy loading routing, but somehow once the page is rendered, I can not re-render the page again to get the updated value on page.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    print("initState only");
    super.initState();
  }
```

The `print("initState only");` is only called once, even when I visit the page many times.

My routing

```
QRoute(
  path: "/",
  builder: () =>  def_dashboard.DashboardView(),
  middleware: [
    DeferredLoader(def_dashboard.loadLibrary),
  ],
),
```